# Double integral over the same variable with partial area

Tags: integration

Can we simplify this?

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} [\int_{-\infty}^x f(h)dh] f(x) dx$

All I know about f is that it has a finite area.

It looks like a moment as it multiplies f(x) by something, but this something is actually the partial area.

(edited)

I forgot part of it (1/x), sorry.

I really want to solve it in a definite form and for intervals above 0:

$\int_{a}^{b} [\int_{a}^x f(h)dh] \frac{f(x)}{x-a} dx$

or the particular case for

$\int_{0^+}^{\infty} [\int_{0^+}^x f(h)dh] \frac{f(x)}{x} dx$

Apologies for the mistake, but this is the one I don't know how to solve. Thank you for your help.

Comment: This simplifies to $$\frac{1}{2}\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\:dx\right)^2$$ if it exists.

Comment: Thank you! Now I've realised this is not actually what I wanted to solved. I forgot a 1/x. See the edited question, sorry.